# utf errors when running script from AWS Lambda but not when running from manual ssh

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, paramiko

I have a python AWS Lambda listening for a github webhook. When it receives one it SSHs (via paramiko) into a remote server and runs a script to regenerate a static website.

Some of the file names for the website contain utf8 characters. The regeneration fails because it can't write the files with these characters.

It is a python static site generator and it outputs this error.

`'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe1' in position`

However if I ssh into the server manually and run the exact same script, it works perfectly.

Do I need to configure paramiko in the lambda in some way to allow utf8? What else could be causing this difference?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I have no incentive to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. When I log in via my shell I think its passing my LANG and LC_ALL environment vars which are set to `en_GB.utf8`. When paramiko on AWS logs in it uses `POSIX` instead which is not utf8. The solution was to prepend all my commands sent via paramiko with `LANG=en_GB.utf8 LC_ALL=en_GB.utf8`